# How to choose best fit using MASS::fitdistr

Tags: r

I have a vector `x`, and then I tried this various distribution to fit with MASS::fitdistr

```
> broom::glance(MASS::fitdistr(x,"normal"))
     n   logLik       AIC      BIC
1 7519 471.6632 -939.3263 -925.476
> broom::glance(MASS::fitdistr(x,"lognormal"))
     n   logLik       AIC       BIC
1 7519 2056.522 -4109.045 -4095.195
> broom::glance(MASS::fitdistr(x,"gamma"))
     n   logLik       AIC       BIC
1 7519 1757.891 -3511.782 -3497.931
> broom::glance(MASS::fitdistr(x,"weibull"))
     n    logLik      AIC     BIC
1 7519 -1148.655 2301.309 2315.16
```

From those values, what distribution is the best and worst that fit `x`. Is  it lognormal(best) and Weibull (worst) or vice versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BIC and AIC are both very similar as they rely on the maximized value (L_hat) of the likelihood function. When comparing models the lowest value shows the best model (for both AIC and BIC). In this case lognormal is the best distribution and Weibull is the worst.

However, although AIC and BIC can be used to compare models they do not tell you anything about how good your model is (since they do not test any hypotheses). In other words, lognormal seems to be fitting the data best compared to the rest of the distributions but you don't know how well it fits your data.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help :)